# Transmitting I2S over 6ft

Tags: audio, adc, rj45, i2s, digital-audio

I've been looking at audio ADCs with most rated at 192Ksps with 24 bit audio.  Typically the output is in I2S, but I understand that the signal is not intended to go far.  I understand that HDMI can transmit I2S but ideally I'd also like to send power over the interface as well, where the 5V at 50mA standard is not going to work.

At worst case, other pins could be stolen for power to use HDMI in a non-standard configuration, but I'm interested in knowing if I could pipe the data across an RJ45 with differential pairs at a distance of 6ft minimum to 20ft max.  Data conversion is flexible, I just don't have any real experience with how sensitive I2S is over distance, and I understand that impedance is a fairly important aspect in reliable transfer, causing most RJ45 interfaces to be very short if used.  Any help or redirection is appreciated, I'm still fairly new to this subject.

Comment: Take a look at https://www.analog.com/media/en/reference-design-documentation/design-notes/dn168f.pdf

Comment: @crj11 Thanks!  I was looking at LVDS before, but I wasn't sure which differential signal type would be best for this and RS-485 slipped my mind.  I appreciate the link, gives me confidence!

Comment: Which kind of interface you need, will it be data, bit clock and word clock only, or do you need master clock too? What's wrong converting that to S/PDIF or AES/EBU or Toslink which will go much further than 20ft you need? Mind that HDMI protocol cannot carry audio packets unless there is active video link too.

Comment: @Justme I haven't finalized an ADC yet, but I'll use the TI PCM186 series as a reference since it's a good option.  The output is exactly that, just data, bit clock, and world clock.  I'm pretty flexible with different interfaces, I was looking at RJ45 originally since it's a very common cable, and with those three signals sent differentially I have the last two pairs for power and ground.  The end goal is to interface with an electric instrument with active pickups.  I'm also okay with using a connector in an unconventional way to achieve results.